# Stop scroll function from queing up

Tags: javascript, scroll

I've created a scroll system with javascript for a site I'm working on and I'm having some trouble with it queing all of the input.

Here's a example of my problem, try scrolling and you will see what the problem is.
http://fadedmeadows.com/test/

```js
var index = 0;
var scroll2 = true;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#home").css({
    "color": "#eb0e0e",
  });
});

$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll touchmove', function(event) {
  scroll2 = true;
  if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
    // scroll up
    if (index > 4) index = 4;

    if (index == 4 && scroll2 == true) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#content3").offset().top
      }, 1000);
      index--;
      scroll2 = false;
    }
    if (index == 3 && scroll2 == true) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#content2").offset().top
      }, 1000);
      index--;
      scroll2 = false;
    }
    if (index == 2 && scroll2 == true) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top
      }, 1000);
      index--;
      scroll2 = false;
    }
    if (index == 1 && scroll2 == true) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("header").offset().top
      }, 1000);
      index--;
      scroll2 = false;
    }
  } else {
    // scroll down
    if (index < 0) index = 0;
    if (index == 0 && scroll2 == true) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#content").offset().top
      }, 1000);
      index++;
      scroll2 = false;
    }
    if (index == 1 && scroll2 == true) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#content2").offset().top
      }, 1000);
      index++;
      scroll2 = false;
    }
    if (index == 2 && scroll2 == true) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#content3").offset().top
      }, 1000);
      index++;
      scroll2 = false;
    }
    if (index == 3 && scroll2 == true) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#content4").offset().top
      }, 1000);
      index++;
      scroll2 = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this will help you but I have a listener for the actual event, and it sets a timeout whenever an event is received.

If the event fires before the previous timeout expires, I cancel the previous one. And the timeout actually triggers the action. So a stream of similar events that occur right after each other is silenced and discarded.

I use this mainly for window resize events but it might apply here too. Pure js code could look something like this:

```
var resizeTimeout = null, wait = 200;
window.onresize = function(){
  if (resizeTimeout !== null) {
    window.clearTimeout(resizeTimeout);
    resizeTimeout = null;
  }
  resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    //do whatever is needed to deal with window resize.
  }, wait);
}
```

(But I have a wrapper "class" called Timer that make it a bit cleaner to do this kind of thing)

Comment: Would I be able to declare "wait" as a variable and still have this code work? I've used similar languages to javascript so the way this is layed out doesn't make sense to me. I feel like this is on the right track but it isn't working for me and I need to finish this website ASAP, thank you in advance.

Comment: Nevermind I fixed the problem, thank you so much for your help. I wish I could upvote you but it wont let me yet.

Comment: @KommanderKrunt no problem. So IIUC, you were able to adapt this method to your use case? If so, cool! Glad it helped you :)